# RegExp. Search MAC-address

Tags: javascript, regex

```
'01:32:54:67:89:AB'.match(/(([A-F0-9]{2}):){5}\2/); //null
```

Why does not link back to the group?

If you write well, it all works:

```
(([A-F0-9]{2}):){5}([A-F0-9]{2})
```

Comment: Are you trying to make sure that it simply matches the correct MAC address pattern, or do you actually want to capture the alphanumeric groups?

Comment: whoever down-voted this question should explain why. It looks like a perfect valid question to me

Comment: @Dalorzo, there seems to be a professional, who know everything, do not pay attention to constantly put minuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\2` is not back reference to the pattern. It is back reference to the 2nd captured group.

In your pattern `89` is captured in the 2nd group.. so it will search for `89`.. hence you are not getting the match.

**For example:**

`(["'])\w+\1`  will match `"Hello"` since both ends on the same first match `"` but it will not match `"Hello'`

Comment: I realized regular expression engine, to find the first bracket expression - remembers it and then \ 1 means "to find the same thing in the first group of the bracket. Right?

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov yes.. exactly.. :)